Stuck queries in status "active" freezing apps
We have a worrying issue on production.
Queries from pg_stat_activity start to hang on status "active". They can be in that status for hours, and don't go away until the server is restarted / apps redeployed. The queries are the simplest they can be, SELECT by an indexed session id column [session validation]). They pile up quickly, and the app's pool thread limit is quickly reached (it is 10 by default), freezing the app.

DB: AWS RDS Postgres
Apps: SvelteKit apps
Postgres adapter: PostgresJS

The issue:

pg_stat_activity shows that queries pile up in status: active
often with the same query_id
the very same SELECT is executed under 10ms on the server (it is not a long-running query:  "fetching: 7 ms")

Here is an example of stuck queries from the pg_stat_activity. As you may see from this example, the query_id is the same, and on is added 9 minutes after the first query.
I usually see queries duplicating like that in the pg_stat_activity query.
[
  {
    "datid": 16461,
    "datname": "auth-db",
    "pid": 21110,
    "leader_pid": null,
    "usesysid": 16460,
    "usename": "auth-db-user",
    "application_name": "postgres.js",
    "client_addr": "x.x.x.132",
    "client_hostname": null,
    "client_port": 37434,
    "backend_start": "2024-10-16 17:39:13.649736 +00:00",
    "xact_start": "2024-10-16 18:03:22.498475 +00:00",
    "query_start": "2024-10-16 18:03:22.498475 +00:00",
    "state_change": "2024-10-16 18:03:22.498478 +00:00",
    "wait_event_type": "Client",
    "wait_event": "ClientRead",
    "state": "active",
    "backend_xid": null,
    "backend_xmin": null,
    "query_id": -6194834080809489076,
    "query": "SELECT * FROM \"user_session\" WHERE id = $1",
    "backend_type": "client backend"
  },
  {
    "datid": 16461,
    "datname": "auth-db",
    "pid": 20583,
    "leader_pid": null,
    "usesysid": 16460,
    "usename": "auth-db-user",
    "application_name": "postgres.js",
    "client_addr": "x.x.x.132",
    "client_hostname": null,
    "client_port": 46586,
    "backend_start": "2024-10-16 17:30:48.670474 +00:00",
    "xact_start": "2024-10-16 18:03:28.508803 +00:00",
    "query_start": "2024-10-16 18:03:28.508803 +00:00",
    "state_change": "2024-10-16 18:03:28.508805 +00:00",
    "wait_event_type": "Client",
    "wait_event": "ClientRead",
    "state": "active",
    "backend_xid": null,
    "backend_xmin": null,
    "query_id": -6194834080809489076,
    "query": "SELECT * FROM \"user_session\" WHERE id = $1",
    "backend_type": "client backend"
  }
]

I have tried a couple of things, none of them worked so far. I'm not even sure if it is an RDS issue, AWS configuration issue, SvelteKit quirk, or otherwise.

It's an application issue, the database is waiting for input from the application. The value for $1, when does it finally come?

Thank you for your input @FrankHeikens. Any chance these queries are hanging because of a network connection issue? - query is sent but the $1 is not.
Also, it is weird that days can pass without an issue, then within 15 minutes it spikes quickly.

You have to debug your application and most likely also the code for PostgresJS.

Thank you Frank. We do see a lot of aborted requests in our error tracking platform, which means that browser (client) requests are aborted to the server. I suspect that some of the aborted requests arrive just at the worst time just after the prepared statement is ready, and before the BIND query. And that is how these queries hang.
WDYT, would this be a feasible scenario?
